# Interpotaliton in degrees

Tags: rotations

If I have a rotation that goes from 0º to 90º and I want to base the rotation on the touch of my finger, how can I calculate this?

My current situation is that if I touch at the end of the object (height equals 150 units) I would like a degree of 0º, if I touch at the very beginning (0) I would like 90º. How can put this into an equation?

Comment: This sounds like a right triangle with a hypotenuse of $150$ and the other two sides being equal. Am I interpreting this correctly? Also you ask how to put this into an equation. What's the equation trying to find?

Comment: if `x=75` it should give me `45º` (for example).

Comment: @JonathanLandrum no. If `x=150` then `y=90` where the goal is to be `0`. The same thing with `x=0` then `y=0`, where goal would be `90º`.

Comment: Is this a slider for a computer program? Try $f(x) = \frac{150 - x}{150} \cdot 90$, which is just $90 - \frac{3}{5}x$. The division by $150$ reverses it and normalizes it to $[0,1]$, and multiplying by $90$ scales it up to the interval you want.

Comment: @HenrySwanson yes it is. Thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like this is the scenario.

You want to find a function $f(x)=y$ such that $f(0)=90$, $f(75)=45$ and $f(150)=0$.

Since the halfway point along $150$ corresponds with the halfway point along $90$, this is looking linear.

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{0-45}{150-75}=\frac{-45}{75}=-\frac{3}{5}$$

So that's your slope. Plug that into the equation for a line.

$$y=mx+b$$
$$y=-\frac{3}{5}x+b$$
$$90=-\frac{3}{5}(0)+b$$
$$b=90$$

Making your equation
$$y=-\frac{3}{5}x+90$$

Comment: That's it. Awesome!